# Swing: Custom LaF for JTabbedPane component subclass

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

How can I subclass a JTabbedPane and give each instance of my subclass a Look-and-Feel that is different from the default LaF? I still want access to the default JTabbedPanel, so simply overriding the global LaF is not an option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually set the specific UI implementation of the JTabbedPane (and most other JComponents) by calling the setUI(TabbedPaneUI ui) method.

For example to set a specific JTabbedPane to use the Metal Look and Feel use:

```
JTabbedPane fooPane = new JTabbedPane();
fooPane.setUI(MetalTabbedPaneUI.createUI(fooPane));
```

When creating a subclass (like you do) of JTabbedPane you will need to override the method updateUI() like this:

```
public void updateUI() {
    setUI(MetalTabbedPaneUI.createUI(this));
}
```

Comment: So, here's what I'm doing in my constructor:

`this.setUI(MetalTabbedPaneUI.createUI(this));`

And (on OS X) it doesn't appear to have any affect when I use MetalPane instead of JTabbedPane

Comment: Updated my answer for your use-case. Does that help?